# Использование include для привязки коллекции к модели

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Есть 2 модели.

Subject:

```
public class Subject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Diary> Diaries { get; set; }

    public Subject()
    {
        Diaries = new List<Diary>();
    }
}
```

Diary:

```
public class Diary
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime EvaluationDate { get; set; }

    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Я хочу вытащить все предметы что у меня есть в таблице subject и привязать к каждому коллекцию diaries.

И это делается по сути не сложно:

```
IEnumerable<Subject> subjects = db.Subjects.Include(i => i.Diaries).ToList();
```

Но мне нужно что бы в каждый предмет вошли записи из таблицы diary ограниченные временным промежутком и для определённого пользователя. Пытаюсь сделать это вот таким вот способом:

```
IEnumerable<Subject> subjects = db.Subjects
    .Include(i => i.Diaries.Where(d => d.EvaluationDate >= startDate
                                    && d.EvaluationDate < endDate
                                    && d.UserId == userId))
    .ToList();
```

Но при таком варианте выходит ошибка.

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
>   Имя параметра: path

Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так? И как можно добиться что бы запрос выполнялся так как я его задумал?

Comment: Вероятно, для этого придется отказаться от Include и делать с помощью Join.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov а с include такое сделать нельзя? Вы бы не могли привести пример с join как это сделать?

Comment: Понял, убрал...

Comment: Можно оставить с include, но фильтровать Diaries там где выводите

Comment: @Андрей NOP если вы имеете в виду на view то мне проще отдельно вытащить по своему условию диариес а потом связать их с сабджект. А как можно сделать что бы сразу отфильтровать? Через join? Вы не могли бы привести пример?